# Normal hashrate but no accepted shares in

Tags: mining-pools, cgminer, gpu

For the moment I'm trying to mine altcoins using an AMD HD6850.
The version of cgminer is 3.7.2. The pool I'm using is prohashing.com.
It's a scrypt-mining pool which mines the most profitable coins at the moment. When I'm connecting to the pool, I get decent hashrates for my GPU (200Mh/s), but I get no accepted shares... When I look on the prohashing profile page I see that next to my worker there's following message:

"This miner is not responding to work restart testing, so a suboptimal default value was chosen. Use the r= password argument to manually set a default value."

My main screen is looking like this:

[image]

My configuration file is as following:

```
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
cgminer.exe -o stratum+tcp://prohashing.com:3333 -u CoinHunter -p "" -I 13 -w 256 --thread-concurrency 6144
```

Changing the difficulty or mining a specific coin didn't do the job...
Someone who has an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

200Mh/s is impossibly high for an HD6850 mining scrypt. My bet is that you're mining SHA256d, not scrypt. I don't see a `-scrypt` in your configuration file.